# Set SERVER vars programatically from the CLI

Tags: linux, php-cli

I need a script to set the SERVER variables programatically when executing a PHP script from the CLI.

The idea is to get the SetEnv lines from an apache config file and feed them into the cli execution of the script so that the CRON job can execute with the same environment variables as the web site.

I have the following command

```
envvars=grep SetEnv $conffile | awk '{print $2"=\""$3"\"";}' | xargs
$envvars php $script
```

which should execute

`arg1="value1" arg2="value2" php somescript.php`

But I get the response

`arg1=value1: command not found`

If I just echo the command I can execute it without a problem.

QUESTION: Why does my bash script not work?

Comment: If you're trying to pass environment variables, why is your program looking in `$_SERVER`? They don't show up there anyway.

Comment: Apache SetEnv directive does. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#121008 http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#97106

Comment: OK, that's Apache-specific then. Environment variables are normally accessed with `getenv()`. You shouldn't rely on that, precisely because it's Apache-specific.

Comment: I am accessing them using `getenv()`. The reason I mention SERVER variables is because I the method used by the command line sets SERVER variables. This line of discussion is not really relevant to the question.

Comment: You should probably clarify your question, then, so others don't get confused too.

Comment: @MichaelHampton there you go.